# Question about proof of Fundamental Theorem of Duality

Tags: functional-analysis, duality-theorems

I have a question about the proof of the following result (from Aliprantis and Border). Recall that $ker f = \{x \in X: f(x)=0\}$.

***Theorem*.** Let $f_1,...,f_n$ be linear functionals on a vector space $X$. Then $f$ lies in the span of $f_1,..., f_n$ (that is, $f = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_if_i$ for some scalars $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$) if and only if $\bigcap_{i=1}^n ker f_i \subset ker f$.

*Proof.* If $f = \sum^n_{i=1} \lambda_i f_i$, then clearly $\bigcap^n_{i=1} ker f_i \subset ker f$. For the converse, assume that$\bigcap^n_{i=1}ker f_i \subset ker f$. Then $T:X\to \mathbb R^n$ via $T(x)= (f_1(x),...,f_n(x))$ is a linear operator. Since$\bigcap^n_{i=1}ker f_i \subset ker f$, if $(f_1(x),..., f_n(x)) = (f_1(y),..., f_n(y))$, then $f_i(x − y) = 0$ for each $i$ and so $f(x) = f(y)$. Thus the linear functional $\phi:T(X) \to \mathbb R$ defined by $\phi(f_1(x),...,f_n(x) = f(x)$ is well defined. **Now note that $\phi$ extends to all of $\mathbb R^n$**, so there exist scalars $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$ such that $\phi(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n) = \sum^n_{i=1} λ_i\alpha_i$. Thus $f(x) = \sum^n_{i=1} \lambda_i f_i(x)$ for each $x \in X$, as desired.

I'm having trouble seeing why $\phi$ can be extended to all of $\mathbb R^n$. The way the proof is written, it seems like this step should be obvious, so I guess I'm missing something easy. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to use something like Hahn-Banach theorem?

Comment: This here might be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3263817/extending-linear-maps-from-subspaces-to-the-entire-space

Answer (score 1):

In finite dimension, every subspace has a complement. Every linear map defined on a subspace can be extended to the whole space by defining the extended map as $0$ on such a complement subspace.

Comment: What do you mean by "complement"?

Comment: If $U$ is a subspace of $E$, I mean a subspace $V$ such that $U \oplus V = E$.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add more details or provide a reference, so I can see how the finite dimensionality is needed for this argument.

Comment: The existence of a complement does not need the vector space to be finite-dimensional. If $U$ is a subspace of $E$, it has a basis $B$. This can be extended to a basis $B'$ of $E$, and then the linear span of $B' \setminus B$ is a complement to $U$.

Comment: @spin Ok, so where does that leave us? I'd still like to understand exactly how the extension in the proof is supposed to work.

Comment: @spin But there is a straightforward proof in finite dimension by adding independent vectors until the dimension of $E$ is reached

Comment: @grndl: This is explained in the answer. To define a linear map it suffices to define it on a basis and then extend linearly. So just define the extension of $\phi$ by $\phi'(x) = \phi(x)$ for $x$ in $T(X)$, and $\phi'(x)$ can be whatever you want for basis elements $x$ outside of $T(X)$, for example zero.